# Reset Windows domain user password

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain, password

Is there a way to reset a domain user password remotely without logging in to a domain controller using Remote Desktop?

I could not find any MMC plugin in non-server Windows (Windows 7 Ultimate in this case) to manage Active Directory which is understandable.

Answer (score 13):

You can download the [Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?familyid=7D2F6AD7-656B-4313-A005-4E344E43997D&displaylang=en).  This will give you all the MMC snap-ins you'd normally find on the Server OSes.  However, the machine you're running this from will likely have to either be a domain member or at least connected to the same network the domain is on in order to connect to your DC remotely.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with the RSAT?

http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?familyid=7D2F6AD7-656B-4313-A005-4E344E43997D&displaylang=en

Active Directory Users and Computers is included

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee449470(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You could use pspasswd from sysinternals tools.

```
usage:  pspasswd [\\computer[,computer[,...] | @file [-u username [-p password]]] Username [NewPassword]]
```

> **computer**
>    Run the command on the computer or computers specified. If you omit the computer name the command runs on the local system and if you enter a computer name of `\\*` then the command runs on all computers in the current domain.
>
> **@file**
>    Execute the command on each of the computers listed in the file.
>
> **-u**
>    Specifies optional user name for login to remote computer.
>
> **-p** 
>    Specifies optional password. If you omit this you will be prompted to enter a hidden password.
>
> **Username**
>    Specifies name of account for password change.
>
> **NewPassword**
>    New password. If ommitted a NULL password is applied.

Comment: You get a +1 from me when you explain how to use it. 
"usage: pspasswd [[\\computer[,computer[,..] | @file [-u user [-p psswd]]] Username [NewPassword]" Unfortunately I do not speak regex

Comment: @Nat, that's not regex. It's the normal way optional parameters are specified, and has been done that way for longer than most members of this site have been breathing.

Comment: I was afraid of that